# $.post serialization for file uploads

Tags: jquery, ajax, file, serialization, upload

This seems to work with my dynamically changing forms that don't require uploads.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://mediahood.net/js/ajaxfileupload.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#txtrform").submit(function(){

    $.post($(this).attr('action'), $(this).serialize(), function(data) {
        $("#col3").load("/include/txtrpbox/feed.php");
        $('input#txtrinput').val('');
    });

    return false;
});

});
</script>
```

But when I add this, the AJAX fails and the forms submit normally reloading the page.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://mediahood.net/js/ajaxfileupload.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#txtrform").submit(function(){

        $.post($(this).attr('action'), $(this).serialize(), function(data) {
            $("#col3").load("/include/txtrpbox/feed.php");
            $('input#txtrinput').val('');
        });

        return false;
    });

    function ajaxFileUpload()
    {
        //starting setting some animation when the ajax starts and completes
        $("#loading")
        .ajaxStart(function(){
            $(this).show();
        })
        .ajaxComplete(function(){
            $(this).hide();
        });

        /*
            prepareing ajax file upload
            url: the url of script file handling the uploaded files
                        fileElementId: the file type of input element id and it will be the index of  $_FILES Array()
            dataType: it support json, xml
            secureuri:use secure protocol
            success: call back function when the ajax complete
            error: callback function when the ajax failed

                */
        $.ajaxFileUpload
        (
            {
                url:$.post($(this).attr('action'),
                secureuri:false,
                fileElementId:'fileToUpload',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data, status)
                {
                    if(typeof(data.error) != 'undefined')
                    {
                        if(data.error != '')
                        {
                            alert(data.error);
                        }else
                        {
                            alert(data.msg);
                        }
                    }
                },
                error: function (data, status, e)
                {
                    alert(e);
                }
            }
        )

        return false;

    } 

});
</script>
```

Why? I would like both my non-upload & upload forms to work.

Im using the script from http://www.phpletter.com/Our-Projects/AjaxFileUpload/

Comment: You are missing a `)` or a `{` on the `$.post` inside of ajaxfileupload function, as-is the syntax is wrong. copy paste error? is `$.post(` even supposed to be there?

Comment: iono i would just like to know how I use the ajaxFileUpload script from [link](http://www.phpletter.com/Our-Projects/AjaxFileUpload/) in conjuction with the working script from the first code box.

Comment: Are they two different forms? or what. it's unclear what you doing at this point. Currently you aren't even calling the function that implements ajax file upload.

Comment: I have six differet forms that share the same ajax post script because its the same form. When i dynamically change the form i modify the action only nd chnge the input. Three of them dnt require uploads so my $.post serialization works. But wen i attempt to complete one of fhe other three for uploads, They dont process. The input=file doesnt do any uploading hence serialization fails.

Answer (score 0):

After a long night, I solved the AJAX uploading issues with the script from malsup.github.io ... The already working $.post I scripted followed the upload and sent the form data to its corresponding php file. #beauty

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://{mysite}/js/ajaxfileupload.js"></script>
<script src="http://{mysite}/js/jquery.form.js"></script> 

<script>
(function() {

var bar = $('.bar');
var percent = $('.percent');
var status = $('#status');

$('#txtrform').ajaxForm({
    beforeSend: function() {
        status.empty();
        var percentVal = '0%';
        bar.width(percentVal)
        percent.html(percentVal);
    },
    uploadProgress: function(event, position, total, percentComplete) {
        var percentVal = percentComplete + '%';
        bar.width(percentVal)
        percent.html(percentVal);
    },
    success: function() {
        var percentVal = '100%';
        bar.width(percentVal)
        percent.html(percentVal);
    },
    complete: function(xhr) {
        status.html(xhr.responseText);
    }
}); 

})();       
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#txtrform").submit(function(){

        $.post($(this).attr('action'), $(this).serialize(), function(data) {
            $("#col3").load("/include/txtrpbox/feed.php");
            $('input#txtrinput').val('');
        });

        return false;
    });

});
</script>
```

Now I can upload various types of documents to the feed on my site including: text(like twitter), embed or uploaded video, imported or uploaded photos, and shared or uploaded audio. That's all I needed.